# Ошибка чтения файлаа

Tags: javascript, express, fs

Не пойму в чем проблема...
Вот ошибка, которую генерирует shell консоль:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//var/www/www-root/data/www/invizzz.com/datas/IDHolders/id_44325/EURUSD#MT4#Alpari International#tick.datas'

А вот реальный файл на сервере с полным доступом 777:
/var/www/www-root/data/www/invizzz.com/datas/IDHolders/id_44325/EURUSD#MT4#Alpari International#tick.datas

При этом проверка на существование файла проверялась предварительно при помощи функции stat. Проверка пройдена успешно, поэтому не понятно почему файл не найден, если он есть... С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: каким образом вы проверяете наличие файла?

Comment: fs.stat("path_to_file", (err)=>{...});

Comment: Проверять файл это или каталог нет смысла, так как он уникальный.

Comment: `path_to_file` это относительный путь? и у вас два слеша в начале пути

Comment: абсолютный конечно же. Получится вот такая строка
//var/www/www-root/data/www/invizzz.com/datas/IDHolders/id_44325/EURUSD#MT4#Alpari International#tick.datas

Comment: @Yugofx, 2 слэша или 1 в общем то разницы нет. у меня другие файлы таким образом читаются... тоже с 1 слэшем. и с двумя... везде на рандоме ставил, но и так и так работает.

Comment: @Yugofx,  все я понял... Это он мне ошибку генерирует видать при попытке прочитать файл, который еще не подгрузился терминалом форекса...